# AS3: Does object have a property stored by default that represents its uniqueness?

Tags: actionscript-3, unique

I've been using a custom base class with an `id` property that is automatically assigned by a manager class when an instance is created. I use this value in multiple ways and require it to differentiate each instance.

I want to remove the need for my own base class but still have a way to tell instances throughout my application apart.

Is there a property set on all objects in ActionScript 3 that can act as a unique identifier?

Comment: Do you wish to "obtain a unique identifier"? (I do not believe such a concept exists.) Or, do you really wish to, given two values, determine if they are the same object?

Comment: I guess the former. Basically I want an integer or similar that is unique to an object, rather than me assigning a unique id manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there aren't any built-in unique IDs like this. What you're doing sounds like the right way to go if you need to track objects. (You can *differentiate* objects with the === operator - that is, you can tell whether two references point to the same object or not. But I gather that's not all you need.)